# How to get specific array value in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to output a specific value from array in php

Below is my code and array is `$content`

```
<?php
$content = $_POST;

for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) {
  $name = 'item_name_'.$i;
  $quantity = 'item_quantity_'.$i;
  $price = 'item_price_'.$i;
  $image='item_image_'.$i;
  $option='item_options_'.$i;
  $total = $content[$quantity]*$content[$price];
}
?>

<?php
print_r( $content );

?>
```

Output is showing as below:

```
Array ( [currency] => INR 
[shipping] => 0 
[tax] => 0 
[taxRate] => 0 
[itemCount] => 3 
[item_name_1] => Our Nest 
[item_quantity_1] => 1 
[item_price_1] => 1900 
[item_options_1] => image: CF01108.jpg, productcode: 602793420 
[item_name_2] => Our Nest 
[item_quantity_2] => 1 
[item_price_2] => 2100 
[item_options_2] => image: CF01110.jpg, productcode: 123870196 
[item_name_3] => Our Nest 
[item_quantity_3] => 1 
[item_price_3] => 1800 
[item_options_3] => image: CF01106.jpg, productcode: 416267436 )
```

How to get `productcode` value in a php variable and echo it?

example:

602793420, 123870196, 416267436

Comment: You want all product code , in this array ? and

what is you expected output ?

Comment: try it with `echo substr($content[$option], strpos($content[$option], 'productcode:')+strlen('productcode:'));` in your for loop

Comment: What is the data type of `item_options_1` value?

Comment: The [`PHP`](http://www.php.net) language offers plenty of functions for [string manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the `productcode` using `explode()` function, like this,

```
$product_code = explode("productcode: ", $option)[1];
```

Here's the reference:

- [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
    $content = $_POST;

    for($i=1; $i < $content['itemCount'] + 1; $i++) {
      $name = 'item_name_'.$i;
      $quantity = 'item_quantity_'.$i;
      $price = 'item_price_'.$i;
      $image='item_image_'.$i;
      $option='item_options_'.$i;
      $product_code = explode("productcode: ", $option)[1];
      $total = $content[$quantity]*$content[$price];
    }
?>
```

Comment: i did't get exactly what i want, but explode() helped me. thank you. i got my answer  $product_code = explode(", ", $content[$option]); did the work

Comment: @AseshaGeorge Glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest this, in case the option of the item will have more values in future.

```
$option = "image: CF01110.jpg, productcode: 123870196";
$options = explode(",", $option);
echo $product_code = explode("productcode: ", $options[1])[1];
```

Thanks
Amit